# How to prevent same component from re-rendering when navigating? React Router v6

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native

I'm new to react and I'm having trouble preventing the components from re-rendering when I navigate to a different page. Im trying to navigate to my Signup and login page which have nothing but a line of text which is the ONLY thing I want displayed.

The problem is that the Navbar re-renders each time I navigate through the links. I tried different times for react-router v6 but the Navbar is always re-rendering below when I navigate. I simply want the text shown only on the screen but the navbar still shows up

I did not include the Navbar as a Route in my code, but it is being shown every time I navigate to a different link as well as my image slider with react bootstrap carousel.

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Navbar from './Components/Navbar/Navbar';
import ImageSlider from './Components/Slideshow/ImageSlider';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import Signup from './Components/Navbar/Signup';
import Login from './Components/Navbar/Login';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">  
    <Router>
      <Navbar></Navbar>
        <Routes>
          <Route path='/Signup' element={<Signup />}></Route> 
          <Route path='/Login' element={<Login />}></Route>
        </Routes>
      </Router>
      <ImageSlider></ImageSlider>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Navbar.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { MenuItems } from "./MenuItems";
import {Link,NavLink} from "react-router-dom";


class Navbar extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return(
            <nav className="NavbarItems">
                <ul className={this.state.clicked ? 'nav-menu active' : 'nav-menu'}>
                    {MenuItems.map((item,index) => {
                        return (
                            <li key={index}>
                                 <NavLink to={item.url} activeClassName="is-active" className={item.cName} style={{position: 'relative', right: 0, top: 13}}>
                                     {item.title}
                                 </NavLink>
                            </li>
                        )
                    })}
                </ul>
            </nav>
        )
    }
}

export default Navbar
```

MenuItems.js

```
export const MenuItems = [
    {
        title: 'Home',
        url: '/',
        cName: 'nav-links'
    },
    {
        title: 'Sign Up',
        url: '/Signup',
        cName: 'nav-links'
    },
    {
        title: 'Login',
        url: '/Login',
        cName: 'nav-links'
    }
]
```

ImageSlider.js

```
import React from 'react';
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
import Carousel from 'react-bootstrap/Carousel';

export default function ImageSlider() {
    return (
      <div className='slideshow' style={{ height:120}}>
        <Carousel controls={false}>
          <Carousel.Item interval={1500}>
            <img
              className="d-block w-100"
              src="https://cdn.suwalls.com/wallpapers/nature/beautiful-sunset-in-grand-canyon-47489-1920x1080.jpg"
              alt="Image One"
            />
          </Carousel.Item>
          <Carousel.Item interval={1500}>
            <img
              className="d-block w-100"
              src="https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/284466.jpg"
              alt="Image Two"
            />
          </Carousel.Item>
          <Carousel.Item interval={1500}>
            <img
              className="d-block w-100"
              src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/09/6a/35/096a35453660aa9b83ba4ab6d9182d61.jpg"
              alt="Image Two"
            />
          </Carousel.Item>
          <Carousel.Item interval={1500}>
            <img
              className="d-block w-100"
              src="https://www.teahub.io/photos/full/2-29537_hd-nature-wallpapers-landscape-green-cute-desktop-waterfall.jpg"
              alt="Image Two"
            />
          </Carousel.Item>
          <Carousel.Item interval={1500}>
            <img
              className="d-block w-100"
              src="https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/825200.jpg"
              alt="Image Two"
            />
          </Carousel.Item>
          <Carousel.Item interval={1500}>
            <img
              className="d-block w-100"
              src="https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/825194.jpg"
              alt="Image Two"
            />
          </Carousel.Item>
          <Carousel.Item interval={1500}>
            <img
              className="d-block w-100"
              src="https://hikinglovers.files.wordpress.com/2014/02/high-mountain-hiking-trail-1920x1080-wallpaper-jjr5fr.jpg"
              alt="Image Two"
            />
          </Carousel.Item>
          <Carousel.Item interval={1500}>
            <img
              className="d-block w-100"
              src="https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/1859582.jpg"
              alt="Image Two"
            />
          </Carousel.Item>
          <Carousel.Item interval={1500}>
            <img
              className="d-block w-100"
              src="https://cdn.suwalls.com/wallpapers/nature/mountain-shadowing-upon-the-lake-54621-1920x1200.jpg"
              alt="Image Two"
            />
          </Carousel.Item>
        </Carousel>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: this seems to be react-router-dom v6, is it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Starting **react-router-dom v6**,
you can split your components and have them rendered only on speicifc routes.

Your `App.js` should be like

```
<Router>
    <Routes>
        <Route element={
            <>
                <Navbar />
                <Outlet />
                <ImageSlider />
            </>
        }>
            // routes for authenticated users where navbar & image slider should be displayed 
            <Route path='/home' element={<Home />}> </Route> 
        </Route>

        <Route element={<Outlet />}>
            // routes where navbar & image slider is not rendered
            <Route path='/Signup' element={<Signup />}> </Route> 
            <Route path='/Login' element={<Login />}> </Route>
        </Route>            
    </Routes>
</Router>
```

By doing this, your `/home` route will always have `Navbar` & `ImageSlider` component, where as the guest routes will have only the element that is passed as prop to the route.

---

As your app grows, I'd suggest to split this into `Layouts` folder to contain

1. Auth Layout - a component that renders all common components for authenticated users
2. Guest Layout - a component that renders all common components for guest users

so that you can leverage from async code like `useEffect` or any other hook.

I've drafted a demo to showcase how you can use achieve this by splitting into seperate components.

https://codesandbox.io/s/multiple-layouts-react-7r8qu

Comment: This was immensely helpful. Thanks! I really appreciate it.